# Do you need to be online to play the X Series?

Tags: x-rebirth

I was reading up on X Rebirth and keep reading that the game like the rest of the series is active even when the player is not present.

for each game Wikipedia says it only has a Single Player Mode and it can come on a physical format but this matters little as Wikipedia had the same information for [SimCity](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=SimCity_%282013_video_game%29&oldid=542619227) (before Offline Mode was released)

So does the X Series require one to be online to play?

Comment: "Active when player is not present" does not mean active when the game is not running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, a persistent internet connection is not required for playing any of the games so far released in the series. A connection is required for Steam activation on the latest game, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

I've checked several sources.

[Source](http://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri?gameName=x-rebirth&itemId=11775&p=r),
[Source2 (in German)](http://www.gamestar.de/spiele/x-rebirth/46889.html#),
[Source3](http://www.deepsilver.com/game-view/view/game/access12/x-rebirth/),
[Source4](http://www.game-debate.com/games/index.php?g_id=1788&game=X%20Rebirth),
[Source5](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=306357)

None says a permanent internet connection is required. Since some of the sources would show something like "permanent internet connection required" for other games, I think one can say that X-Rebirth doesn't require one!

Answer (score 1):

You need a persistent internet connection to play Dead-is-Dead mode in the X3 series.  Connection drops have led to frustration, and a tendency to avoid playing this mode.

X-Rebirth is a Steam required game, but you can certainly play it in offline mode.  Subscriptions to mods, etc. in the Workshop will not sync in Offline mode.